# How do I display a ratio in Excel in the format A:B?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet of data like:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
33        11
25        5
6         4
```

What i would like to do is add a third column which shows the ratio of columnA to columnB in the format of A:B. For example:

```
ColumnA ColumnB   Ratio
33        11       3:1
25        5    5:1
6         4    3:2
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are looking for the greatest common divisor (GCD).

You can calculate it recursively in VBA, like this:

```
Function GCD(numerator As Integer, denominator As Integer)
  If denominator = 0 Then
    GCD = numerator
  Else
    GCD = GCD(denominator, numerator Mod denominator)
  End If
End Function
```

And use it in your sheet like this:

```
   ColumnA   ColumnB   ColumnC
1  33        11        =A1/GCD(A1; B1) & ":" & B1/GCD(A1; B1)
2  25         5        =A2/GCD(A2; B2) & ":" & B2/GCD(A2; B2)
```

It is recommendable to store the result of the function call in a hidden column and use this result to avoid calling the function twice per row:

```
   ColumnA   ColumnB   ColumnC        ColumnD
1  33        11        =GCD(A1; B1)   =A1/C1 & ":" & B1/C1
2  25         5        =GCD(A2; B2)   =A2/C2 & ":" & B2/C2
```

Comment: Just so you know, Excel has a GCD function. You don't really need VBA for this solution at all:) http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052091041033.aspx

Comment: @Aaron: Just so you know ;-), this cell function does not seem to be available before Excel 2007. Believe it or not, not everybody has switched yet.

Comment: As you might have guessed I am using 2007. However I *did* check first. This article says it applies to 2003 http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052091041033.aspx

Comment: @AaronBush both of your links are broken.

Comment: @spikey Try web.archive.com (Comments cannot be edited anyway, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 30):

Try this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1/B1,"?/?"),"/",":")
```

Result:

```
A   B   C
33  11  3:1
25  5   5:1
6   4   3:2
```

Explanation:

- TEXT(A1/B1,"?/?") turns A/B into an improper fraction
- SUBSTITUTE(...) replaces the "/" in the fraction with a colon

This doesn't require any special toolkits or macros. The only downside might be that the result is considered text--not a number--so you can easily use it for further calculations.

---

**Note:** as @Robin Day suggested, increase the number of question marks (?) as desired to reduce rounding (thanks Robin!).

Comment: To make this formula more accurate you can replace it with
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1/B1,"??????????/??????????"),"/",":")

This makes rounding issues less likely.

Comment: please, it's semi-colons, not commas

Answer (score 7):

The second formula on that page uses the GCD function of the Analysis ToolPak, you can add it from Tools > Add-Ins.

=A1/GCD(A1,B1)&":"&B1/GCD(A1,B1)

This is a more mathematical formula rather than a text manipulation based on.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the formula I use. I had a problem using GCD, because I use fairly large numbers to calculate the ratios from, and I found ratios such as "209:1024" to be less useful than simply rounding so it displays either "1:*" or "*:1". I also prefer not to use macros, if at all possible. Below is the result.

```
=IF(A1>B1,((ROUND(A1/B1,0))&":"&(B1/B1)),((A1/A1)&":"&(ROUND(B1/A1,0))))
```

Some of the formula is unnecessary (e.g., "A1/A1"), but I included it to show the logic behind it. Also, you can toggle how much rounding occurs by playing with the setting on each ROUND function.

Comment: great answer and much more useful when you have larger numbers

Answer (score 1):

I found this to be the easiest and the shortest, I however rounded off to zero decimal places:

`="1" & ":" & ROUND((A1/B1),0)`

Note the spaces before and after `&`.

What this means is that "1" and ":" are seen as additional non-formula information to the overall formula. The `ROUND` function rounds off A1/B1 that is the basic formula to 0 decimal places. you can try changing to 1,2,3... decimal places.

I hope I made this clear.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you have data in D and E cells.. 
Here is an easiest ratio displaying fn by my frnd 'Karthik'

```
=ROUND(D7/E7, 2) &":" & (E7/E7)
```

Answer (score 1):

At work we only have Excel 2003 available and these two formulas seem to work perfectly for me:

```
=(ROUND(SUM(B3/C3),0))&":1"
```

or

```
=B3/GCD(B3,C3)&":"&C3/GCD(B3,C3)
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks ya'll. I used this:

```
=CONCATENATE((number1/GCD(number1,number2)),":",((number2/GCD(number1,number2))))
```

If you've got 2007 this works great.

Comment: This fails for scenarios where number1 = 0